# Adding drivers to Yocto raspberry pi image

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, yocto, bitbake

I want to add the AD5628(http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/AD5064.html) DAC Device drivers to kernel in the yocto.

So i have build a yocto image for raspberry Pi by following the guide http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-raspberrypi/about/

Now i want to add the Dac Driver module to kernel so i tried to bitbake command

`bitbake -c menuconfig rpi-hwup-image`

so that i can get a configuration menu and can add the drivers . But it is giving me error saying that menu configure does not exists for the target . So i tried

```
 bitbake linux-raspberrypi -c menuconfig
```

But i am getting error

`"there was error creating child process for this terminal, failed to execute child process "oe-gnome-terminal-phonehome" (no such files or directory)` ".

So someone please help me to add AD5628 driver to the kernel . Thanks

Comment: The driver code is located in the build/tmp/work-shared/drivers/iio/dac/AD5628.c , But i am not getting to how to add to the image

Comment: if anyone could help me by specifying how to add the dac driver to my image . the drivers are already present in the yocto/build/temp/work-shared/drivers/iio/dac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to create a .bbappend file in the meta-layer directory (in my case it should be meta-raspberrypi) , The contents of bbappend file should be

```
SRC_URI += "file:///path/to/config.cfg"
```

then create a config.cfg in the same directory and contents should be

```
CONFIG_AD5604 = y
```

I have given the name AD5604 because that driver suports the ad5628 device.

thanks for the support

Comment: How did that work, shouldn't bbappend look like this:

`FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"`
`SRC_URI += "file://myconfig.cfg"`

If myconfig is located at `meta-mylayer/recipes-kernel/linux/files/myconfig.cfg`